# is possible cascading view in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new at angularjs. I and I read that I can define only one **ng-view** directive in single page application. I want to create cascading like view.

[image]

Nvaigation menu is static. If user click a menu item, the list panel will appear. And if user click edit an item then edit menu will appear.

should I define multiple **ng-view**?

Answer (score 5):

Angular's built in router is fairly limited. Yes, it does support only one `ng-view` per page.

The Angular UI team has put together ui-router, which supports mutiple nested `ui-view`s

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 1):

What about this hierarchy?:

```
<div ng-controller="menuCtrl"></div>
<div ng-view>
  <div>item list</div>
  <div ng-show="itemSelected">edit form</div>
</div>
```

You can define menu as static element. Inside `ng-view` you could place different lists views and if you select an item, you can open an edit form inline or redirect to edit view form.

Sample routing:

```
$routeProvider.when('/products/',{templateUrl: 'productsList.html' controller: 'productsList'});
$routeProvider.when('/products/edit',{templateUrl: 'productEdit.html' controller: 'productEdit'});
```